# Fail to import product with product images at Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2, import

I've placed a image file in the folder "pub/media/import" for product image, and run the below script, but I got an error message.

```
$fullImagePath = "pub/media/import/icn_status.png";
echo $fullImagePath;
if (file_exists($fullImagePath)) {
    try {

        $simple_product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullImagePath, array('image'), false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Can not find image';
}
```

ERROR:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]

The image does not exist.
```

Comment: I may be wrong but don't you have to call `$simple_product->save();` after adding the images to the product ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, the $simple_product is created by magento objectManager 

 $simple_product = $this->objectManger->create('\Magneto\Catalog\Model\Product');

Answer (score 6):

Thanks,

I've checked there is no problem on my code. The problem is file location. I just amended the image file path, the problem has been solved.

```
$fullImagePath = "/import/icn_status.png";
echo $fullImagePath;
if (file_exists("pub/media".$fullImagePath)) {
    try {
        $simple_product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullImagePath, array('image'), false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Can not find image';
}
```

P.S.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to P.S. answer and explain why the file path should be relative to media folder:

**addImageToMediaGallery** calls **Model\Product\Gallery\Processor.php::addImage**

```
 $file = $this->mediaDirectory->getRelativePath($file);
 if (!$this->mediaDirectory->isFile($file)) {
      throw new LocalizedException(__('The image does not exist.'));
 }
```

You can do a debug of the **$file**, and then keep digging which will eventually bring you to **Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read**

Particularly this *line 219*: **$this->driver->getAbsolutePath($this->path, $path)**

Now, if your path was "**/pub/media/import/icn_status.png**" then by debugging the result of **getAbsolutePath** call, you will get something like this:

**/yoursite/public_html/pub/media**/pub/media/import/icn_status.png

So your path is prefixed with the full server path to your media folder.

Hope it makes it more clear now.